# can't find module after creating container from image docker from github respository

Tags: node.js, image, docker, docker-compose, containers

I am new to docker and now i try to create image from github reposistory (app nodejs and mongodb) and create container from that image.

Step:

- create image with

  docker build -t from-api-mkf (url the repo)
- create container with (docker compose)

  ```
  version: "3.4"                                                                    
  services:
    mongodb:
        image: mongo:4.2.3-bionic
        container_name: mongodb
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 27018:27017
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=testdb
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=
    api-mkf:
        image: from-api-mkf
        build:
            context: /home/wuku/sources/api-mkf/ (source from github repo with clone)
            dockerfile: /home/wuku/sources/api-mkf/Dockerfile (source from github repo with clone)
        container_name: api-mkf
        restart: always
        ports: 
            - 8080:80
        volumes:
            - /home/wuku/setup:/setup
            - /home/wuku/sources/api-mkf:/var/www/app
            - /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts
        working_dir: /var/www/app
        links: 
            - mongodb
  ```
- Dockerfile

> ```
> FROM node:14
>
> RUN mkdir -p /var/www/app
>
> # Create app directory
> WORKDIR /var/www/app
>
> # Install app dependencies
> # A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
> # where available (npm@5+)
> COPY package*.json ./
>
> # Bundle app source
> COPY . .
>
> RUN npm install
> # If you are building your code for production
> # RUN npm ci --only=production
>
> EXPOSE 8080
> CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
> ```

- package.json

> ```
> {
>   "name": "rest-api",
>   "version": "1.0.0",
>   "description": "Rest API",
>   "main": "index.js",
>   "scripts": {
>     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
>     "start": "node index.js"
>   },
>   "author": "",
>   "license": "ISC",
>   "dependencies": {
>     "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
>     "cors": "^2.8.5",
>     "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
>     "express": "^4.17.1",
>     "mongoose": "^5.12.10",
>     "pm2": "^4.5.6",
>     "tunnel-ssh": "^4.1.4",
>     "morgan": "^1.9.1",
>     "winston": "^3.2.1"
>   },
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "morgan": "^1.9.1",
>     "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
>     "winston": "^3.2.1"
>   },
>   "engines": {
>     "node": "14.x"
>   }
> }
> ```

- error ( docker logs --tail 50 --follow --timestamps api-mkf)

  > 2021-06-09T01:38:52.499894700Z Error: Cannot find module 'winston'
  > 2021-06-09T01:38:52.499905200Z Require stack:
  > 2021-06-09T01:38:52.499963000Z - /var/www/app/utils/logger.js
  > 2021-06-09T01:38:52.499980700Z - /var/www/app/utils/index.js
  > 2021-06-09T01:38:52.499991300Z - /var/www/app/index.js
  > 2021-06-09T01:38:52.500002200Z     at Function.Module._resolveFilename
  > (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15) 2021-06-09T01:38:52.500021400Z
  > at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
  > 2021-06-09T01:38:52.500032400Z     at Module.require
  > (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19) 2021-06-09T01:38:52.500044700Z
  > at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
  > 2021-06-09T01:38:52.500056500Z     at Object.
  > (/var/www/app/utils/logger.js:1:46) 2021-06-09T01:38:52.500068400Z
  > at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
  > 2021-06-09T01:38:52.500078900Z     at Object.Module._extensions..js
  > (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
  > 2021-06-09T01:38:52.500117700Z     at Module.load
  > (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32) 2021-06-09T01:38:52.500127400Z
  > at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
  > 2021-06-09T01:38:52.500136700Z     at Module.require
  > (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19) {
  > 2021-06-09T01:38:52.500145700Z   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  > 2021-06-09T01:38:52.500157100Z   requireStack: [
  > 2021-06-09T01:38:52.500167500Z     '/var/www/app/utils/logger.js',
  > 2021-06-09T01:38:52.500176700Z     '/var/www/app/utils/index.js',
  > 2021-06-09T01:38:52.500185800Z     '/var/www/app/index.js'
  > 2021-06-09T01:38:52.500195400Z   ] 2021-06-09T01:38:52.500204000Z }

I using window 10 and docker dekstop.

as you can see, it's can't find module winston.
is the package.json dependency not installed ??

thanks for your help

Comment: Your `volumes:` are hiding all of the work the Docker image does.  Does deleting the `volumes:` help (except for what you're mounting into `/setup`, and the storage for your MongoDB)?

Comment: @DavidMaze yeah i try it and it's successfull